# Table view issues in swift iOS

Tags: uitableview, swift, uisearchbar, xcode6.3

I am trying to create a table view in which it has list of dishes with sections and when we select a row it should go to new table view which consist list of popular restaurants which serves that specific food.

I have created the table view with sections, but my app crashes when I reach at end of the list view. I have added my code below with the snapshot of table view and error.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var dishtable: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var namlbl: UILabel!
var Dishes = ["POPULAR Dishes": ["Biryani", "Tandori Chicken","Butter Chicken", "Vada Pav"],"A": ["Aloo baingan", "Aloo ki Tikki", "Amritsari fish"], "B": ["Baigan bharta", "Biryani"]];


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dishtable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    dishtable.dataSource = self
     dishtable.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

let sections:Array<AnyObject> = ["POPULAR Dishes","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
var usernames = [String]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cellID = "cell"

    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.dishtable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID) as! UITableViewCell
    println("value : \(indexPath.section)")
    println("value 1: \(indexPath.row)")

    cell.textLabel!.text = Dishes[sections[indexPath.section] as! String]![indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    println("Dishes section count : \(section)")

    return Dishes.count
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{

    return 27
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String,
    atIndex index: Int) -> Int{

        return index
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

        return self.sections[section] as? String
}
```

This is screenshot for the table view.

[image: Table view]

This is the screenshot of the error when I scroll down to bottom of the table view.

[image: error while scrolling down]

This is the screenshot of the console for the same error.

[image: error shown in the console]

Please also let me know how can we add the search feature for the table view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue lies here:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
  println("Dishes section count : \(section)")

  return Dishes.count
}
```

You are returning a count of rows for each section, yet there are no dishes past key B in `Dishes`.
Normally in a `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method you would do something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
  println("Dishes section count : \(section)")

  if section == 0 {
    return Dishes["POPULAR Dishes"].count
  }
  else if section == 1 {
    return Dishes["A"].count
  }
  return 0
}
```

Obviously you'll want to find a nicer way to do this, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in `numberOfRowsInSection` function.

As in your case `numberOfSectionsInTableView` = 27 so u need to return individual `numberOfRowsInSection`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return Dishes["POPULAR Dishes"].count
    case 1:
        return Dishes["A"].count
    case 2:
        return Dishes["B"].count

    // upto case 26      
    default:
        println("fetal error")
    }
    return 1
}
```