# How can numberOfRowsInSection function of TableView return multiple values for the same section?

Tags: swift, uitableview

[image]Here, I have a TableView with one section. However, I have 2 cells. I want numberofRowsInSection to return 2 different values for different rows of the same section. But, I can't access the row in numberofRowsInSection function. Can someone please tell me how to attain this?

[image]

Comment: refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476340/table-view-issues-in-swift-ios/30476653#30476653

Comment: The solution written there is for multiple section. I am searching an answer for single section

Comment: can you show me an image of your storyboard and/or code so I can understand this better

Comment: just did. please check. Uploaded two images

Comment: Please always post actual code as text, not as screenshots only. Thanks. Picture of code is not searchable, not indexable and not testable.

Comment: I think you are confused a bit. numberOfRowsInSection should return the number of CELLS aka rows in the section, I cannot see what do you mean by returning different number of rows for each row? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numberOfRowsInSections should return the count of cells in that section, if you want to display two different type of cell (ex. CellType1 and CellType2), you should do logic inside

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
       if(indexPath.row == 0){ return CellType1; }
       if (indexPath.row == 1) { return CellType2; }
    }
}
```

you can't return multiple values from that method, apple has not written that method to return multiple values